# Derive random seed from UUID

Tags: go, random, uuid

To produce deterministic randomization for subsequent requests of clients I need to seed a random generator based on an UUID.

Is there a good way for doing this? The approach I am currently considering taking would be:

```golang
number := new(big.Int)
target := new(big.Int)
number.SetBytes(uuid.Bytes())
seed := number.Mod(target, big.NewInt(math.MaxInt64)).Int64()
```

Which is flawed in the sense that it makes collisions more likely but okay right now given there are only few requests coming in.

Comment: It depends on how the UUID is derived and what the randomness is being used for.  What kind of collisions are you talking about, and why does your current approach make them more likely?

Comment: 1 in 2³¹-1 is quite a long shot for collisions!

Answer (score 2):

In general I think you should at least hash the UUID bytes before using them as a seed.

(You should know, I'm not a cryptography or security expert. This is just my analysis based on my understanding and some quick googling).

```
number := new(big.Int)
target := new(big.Int)
// Get hash of the UUID
sum := md5.Sum(uuid.Bytes())[:]
number.SetBytes(sum)
seed := number.Mod(target, big.NewInt(math.MaxInt64)).Int64()
```

Taking the modulus is essentially just taking a certain number of least significant bits. UUID format has a layout where groups of bytes are for specific information.

If using [google's UUID](https://github.com/google/uuid), you're actually only getting about 15 bits of entropy here.  This is because of the UUID format.

By taking on mod math.MaxInt64, you're taking in the least significant 63 bits (~8 bytes) of the UUID.  However, the last 6 bytes (48 bits) are dedicated to the "Node id". This is an identifier associated with which "node" generated the UUID. This means that for any UUIDs generated on the same node, those 48 bits will be the same. The next higher 2 bytes are clock sequence values, which should be a decent source of entropy, but you're only getting 15 bits (63 - 48) of it.

After hashing the UUID, you've essentially "mixed the entropy around", so that you don't have to worry if particular spans of bits are relatively static or not.

See the original RFC declaring the layout standard
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1.2

If you are using some other UUID library, you should verify that they are actually following this standard.

Comment: What is the upside of hashing the UUID bytes?

Comment: @Mahoni See the part about "After hashing the UUID ...". A cryptographic hash function (such as md5) should have the property where each bit of the output will appear random, even given inputs that follow a similar pattern.  See [Avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect).